# Google App Engine: Safe to reuse the same cursor for the same batch of results?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Say I'm iterating over a bunch of results with a cursor enabled 5 elements at a time.

Is the cursor ID for any given batch of 5 elements safe to reuse (as in an exception won't be thrown and I'll always get the same results)?

I'm carrying out some tests locally and it seems that every time I pass the same cursor to the query, I get the exact same results, but was wondering if this is a defined, consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Query Cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors) (emphasis mine):

> A *query cursor* is a small opaque data structure representing a
>   resumption point in **a query**. This is useful for showing a user a page
>   of results at a time; it's also useful for handling long jobs that
>   might need to stop and resume. A typical way to use them is with a
>   query's `fetch_page()` method. It works somewhat like `fetch()`, but
>   it returns a triple `(results, cursor, more)`. The returned `more`
>   flag indicates that there are probably more results; a UI can use
>   this, for example, to suppress a "Next Page" button or link. To
>   request subsequent pages, pass the cursor returned by one
>   `fetch_page()` call into the next.

Fundamentally the cursor simply represents the current position (index if you want) in the list of the query's results.

You can only get the same results displayed (guaranteed I mean) for a cursor **only if** the list of query results doesn't change.

If the list of results changes (be it because of the number of the items in the list changes or because their order in the result list changes) then the results displayed *might* change.

Comment: Thank you, can you put a link to the source, please? Would probably be helpful to read the rest of the document.

Comment: Done. Thanks for noticing the omission.